# Radar chart with multiple scales on multiple axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot a radar chart with multiple scales on multiple axes using `matplotlib`. [The official API example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/radar_chart.html) gives only one scale on one axis. (Scales are 0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8 in this example)

I want different scales on all axes. (There are 9 axes in the given example.)

I found an example of what I am looking for [here](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/archive/2011/09/few.png). There are 5 axes on this example and 5 scales on all axes just like I want.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you can plot this with multiple axes, the lines are in the first axe, and other axes only shows ticklabels.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

class Radar(object):

    def __init__(self, fig, titles, labels, rect=None):
        if rect is None:
            rect = [0.05, 0.05, 0.95, 0.95]

        self.n = len(titles)
        self.angles = np.arange(90, 90+360, 360.0/self.n)
        self.axes = [fig.add_axes(rect, projection="polar", label="axes%d" % i) 
                         for i in range(self.n)]

        self.ax = self.axes[0]
        self.ax.set_thetagrids(self.angles, labels=titles, fontsize=14)

        for ax in self.axes[1:]:
            ax.patch.set_visible(False)
            ax.grid("off")
            ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)

        for ax, angle, label in zip(self.axes, self.angles, labels):
            ax.set_rgrids(range(1, 6), angle=angle, labels=label)
            ax.spines["polar"].set_visible(False)
            ax.set_ylim(0, 5)

    def plot(self, values, *args, **kw):
        angle = np.deg2rad(np.r_[self.angles, self.angles[0]])
        values = np.r_[values, values[0]]
        self.ax.plot(angle, values, *args, **kw)



fig = pl.figure(figsize=(6, 6))

titles = list("ABCDE")

labels = [
    list("abcde"), list("12345"), list("uvwxy"), 
    ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"],
    list("jklmn")
]

radar = Radar(fig, titles, labels)
radar.plot([1, 3, 2, 5, 4],  "-", lw=2, color="b", alpha=0.4, label="first")
radar.plot([2.3, 2, 3, 3, 2],"-", lw=2, color="r", alpha=0.4, label="second")
radar.plot([3, 4, 3, 4, 2], "-", lw=2, color="g", alpha=0.4, label="third")
radar.ax.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting this error - "global name 'angles' is not defined". Could you please add what are the changes you did.

Comment: @Bharathi, bug fixed.

Comment: Perhaps it's useful to note that if you want to see some output of the code above you have to add at least fig.savefig("somename.png") at the end.

Comment: Also I had a problem using the example above with degrees greater than 360 for axis. I.e. the dashed line for the title "A" was missing. I solved this issue by adding a new line with "self.angles = [a % 360 for a in self.angles]" after "self.angles = np.arange(90, 90+360, 360.0/self.n)". Environment: Python 2.7.12 :: Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit), matplotlib (1.5.3), numpy (1.11.1). Anyway thanks for your work ;-)

Comment: Had the same problem as @keocra, probably the libraries got updated and now behave differently. Here's my working solution for a 12-axis radar chart: https://gist.github.com/geberl/c65517bf8273552486f9a8954e80ddf4

Comment: Yeah, the original solution no longer works, but Günther Eberl's is good.

Answer (score 1):

This accepts a dataframe of ints/floats and one id-column and dynamically generates the radar chart. Works irrespective of the range of each column because all values are internally scaled to be between [0,1] (techincally 0 and 1/1.25 since I wanted to give some padding), and simply prints a text of the actual value at the right location.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def spider(df, *, id_column, title=None, max_values=None, padding=1.25):
    categories = df.dtypes[(df.dtypes == 'float') | (df.dtypes == 'int')].index.tolist()
    data = df[categories].to_dict(orient='list')
    ids = df[id_column].tolist()
    if max_values is None:
        max_values = {key: padding*max(value) for key, value in data.items()}
        
    normalized_data = {key: np.array(value) / max_values[key] for key, value in data.items()}
    num_vars = len(data.keys())
    tiks = list(data.keys())
    tiks += tiks[:1]
    angles = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, num_vars, endpoint=False).tolist() + [0]
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8), subplot_kw=dict(polar=True))
    for i, model_name in enumerate(ids):
        values = [normalized_data[key][i] for key in data.keys()]
        actual_values = [data[key][i] for key in data.keys()]
        values += values[:1]  # Close the plot for a better look
        ax.plot(angles, values, label=model_name)
        ax.fill(angles, values, alpha=0.15)
        for _x, _y, t in zip(angles, values, actual_values):
            t = f'{t:.2f}' if isinstance(t, float) else str(t)
            ax.text(_x, _y, t, size='xx-small')
            
    ax.fill(angles, np.ones(num_vars + 1), alpha=0.05)
    ax.set_yticklabels([])
    ax.set_xticks(angles)
    ax.set_xticklabels(tiks)
    ax.legend(loc='upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(0.1, 0.1))
    if title is not None: plt.suptitle(title)
    plt.show()
    
radar = spider

spider(
    pd.DataFrame({
        'x': [*'abcde'],
        'c1': [10,11,12,13,14],
        'c2': [0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.9],
        'c3': [1e5, 2e5, 3.5e5, 8e4, 5e4],
        'c4': [9, 12, 5, 2, 0.2],
        'test': [1,1,1,1,5]
    }),
    id_column='x',
    title='Sample Spider',
    padding=1.1
)
```

[image]