# Spider / radar chart with multiple scales on multiple axes (plot both factors and continuous data) using R

Tags: r, ggplot2, radar-chart, spider-chart

I've this `df`:

```
df<- data.frame ("var.a" = .7,
"var.b" =  3.5,
"var.c" = as.factor("e"),
"var.d" = as.factor("f1"),
"var.e" = as.integer(1),
"var.f" = as.factor("y") )
```

I would like to produce a radar (spider) chart like this:
[image]

Is there any way to produce this chart through R?

In addition I would like to estimate the spider web area in percentage.

Comment: You might look into [ggradar](https://github.com/ricardo-bion/ggradar), though I haven't used it myself

Comment: I'm not familiar with `ggradar`, however for what I have seen is not possible to plot both factors and continuous vectors

Comment: I found what I want using [pyton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24669479/3519756) or this other [example](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/6593). BTW I would like to have an R script