# Radar chart (Spider chart) with multiple scales on multiple axes using R

Tags: r, axis-labels, radar-chart, spider-chart

Good morning,
I am trying to produce a radar chart presenting several football players' statistics with R.

These statistics have different scales and I don't want to rescale them. For a given player and for every axis of my plot, I want to have the minimum value in my sample as origin, the maximum value in my sample as axis maximum value, and the player's value on the axis.

Do you know how I can have different axis limits on my radar?

Here is an example of what I'd like to do:

[Statsbomb example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjkIG.png)

And here is a data sample:

```
colnames <- c("accuratePass","bigChanceCreated","duelWon","goalAssist","goals")
max <- c(78.3, 0.741, 9.61, 0.429, 0.871)
min <- c(3.3, 0.000, 0.11, 0.000, 0.000)
example <- c(15.4, 0.353, 3.41, 0.147, 0.059)
df <- as.data.frame(rbind(max,min,example))
colnames(df) <- colnames
```

The best I have been able to do is below. I am unable to show min values.

```
radarchart(df,
           seg = 10, # 10 segments per axis
           axistype = 2,  # allow axis labels on the outer edge
           paxislabels = round(df[1,],2), # values displayed on the outer edge
           cglcol="grey", cglty=1, axislabcol="blue") # custom grid
```

[Best I can do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQYRx.png)

Comment: Did you try library ```ggradar```? https://exts.ggplot2.tidyverse.org/ggradar.html

Comment: Hi, thanks. 
I tried but I didn't see any option to customize every axis, unfortunately (maybe I looked at it wrong).

Comment: Look there, a python solution: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6084/how-do-i-create-a-complex-radar-chart and there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24659005/radar-chart-with-multiple-scales-on-multiple-axes